# javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/pool/KeyedObjectPoolFactory

Tags: java, oracle10g, database-connection, apache-commons-dbcp

I'm trying to establish a connection to an Oracle database using [`BasicDataSource`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbcp/apidocs/org/apache/commons/dbcp2/BasicDataSource.html) using [DBCP](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbcp/configuration.html).

I downloaded [`commons-dbcp-1.4-bin.zip`](http://www.eu.apache.org/dist//commons/dbcp/binaries/commons-dbcp-1.4-bin.zip) from [here](http://commons.apache.org/dbcp/download_dbcp.cgi).

There are three jar files on the classpath.

1. commons-dbcp-1.4
2. <s>commons-dbcp-1.4-sources</s>
3. commons-dbcp-1.4-javadoc

I'm using the following code for the connection to be established.

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource;

public class DatabaseConnection {

    private final static BasicDataSource BASIC_DATA_SOURCE = new BasicDataSource();
    private final static String SQL = "SELECT * FROM admin WHERE login_id=? AND admin_pwd=?";

    static {
        BASIC_DATA_SOURCE.setDriverClassName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");
        BASIC_DATA_SOURCE.setUrl("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe");
        BASIC_DATA_SOURCE.setUsername("wagafashiondb");
        BASIC_DATA_SOURCE.setPassword("root");
    }

    private static Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
        return BASIC_DATA_SOURCE.getConnection();
    }

    public boolean exists(String userName, String password) throws SQLException {
        Connection connection = null;
        PreparedStatement ps = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        boolean exists = false;

        try {
            connection = getConnection();
            ps = connection.prepareStatement(SQL);
            ps.setString(1, userName);
            ps.setString(2, password);
            rs = ps.executeQuery();
            exists = rs.next();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (connection != null) {connection.close();}
                if (ps != null) {ps.close();}
                if (rs != null) {rs.close();}
            } catch (SQLException e) {

            }
        }
        return exists;
    }
}
```

It throws the following exception,

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/pool/KeyedObjectPoolFactory
```

It appears to imply that I'm using a wrong source. What might be the reason for this exception to be caused?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Solution

You need to get the `commons-pool` library (JAR) on a classpath.
The fact is indicated as `commons-pool` being a dependency of `commons-dbcp` in [project's dependecies list](http://commons.apache.org/dbcp/dependencies.html)

Explanation

Basically the `NoClassDefFoundError` means the Java execution turned out to require a specific class which is not on classpath. This is because classes needs other classes (typically indicated in `import`s). In your case (at least) one of the classes from `commons-dbcp` declares a dependency to `org/apache/commons/pool/KeyedObjectPoolFactory`.

The name of the class is given using `/` as separators. If that's a common name (not your own class), you may try to find where to get it from by just typing the full name (e.g. `org/apache/commons/pool/KeyedObjectPoolFactory`) in Google.